# Land cover classification using Google Earth Engine, and involving SAVI and EVI indices

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, random-forest

I'm trying to do a land cover classification using Landsat-8 OLI/TIRS. However, I want to involve indexes (SAVI, and EVI) in this classification process. I don't know how to solve this problem. Is there any solution to this problem?

Here's my GEE script:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/d69d129c59695b3c60ba1245e8ed2c20

```
//Sumber: Wahyuni

Map.addLayer(Indragiri);

var image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
            .filterBounds(roi)
            .filterDate('2014-01-01', '2014-12-31')
            .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than', 10)
            .sort('CLOUD_COVER', true);
print(image);


var featurecol = forest.merge(agriculture).merge(urban).merge(water).merge(baren).merge(cloud);


//SAVI: Soil-Adjusted Vegetation Index
var savi = image.map(function(image) {
  return image.expression('1.5 * (NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED + 5000)', {
                        'NIR': image.select('B5'),
                        'RED': image.select('B4')
                    }).rename('SAVI')});


//EVI: Enhanced Vegetation Index
var evi = image.map(function(image) {
  return image.expression('(2.5 * ((NIR - RED)) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
                        'NIR': image.select('B5'),
                        'RED': image.select('B4'),
                        'BLUE': image.select('B2')
                    }).rename('EVI')});



var bands = (['SAVI', 'EVI', 'B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7']);
var training = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: featurecol, 
  properties: ['LandCover'],
  scale: 30
});

var trained = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(6)
              .train({
                  features: training, 
                  classProperty: 'LandCover',
                  inputProperties: bands
              });

var classified = image.select(bands).classify(trained);

Map.centerObject(roi, 11);
Map.addLayer(classified,
             {min: 0, max: 5, palette: ['157B16', '8ADA15', '15DAAD','DAAE15','F8EECB','E3E3E2']},
             'classification');

for(var LandCover = 0; LandCover < 6; LandCover++){
  var area = classified.eq(LandCover).multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
  var calculatearea = area.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: Indragiri,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
    
  })
  print('Luas' + LandCover + ' ' + 'hectares', calculatearea, ee.Number(calculatearea.values().get(0)).divide(1e6))}

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified,
  description: 'Klasifikasi',
  region: Indragiri,
  maxPixels: 1e9,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mix-up: `image` is actually not an image, but a collection of images. I'm guessing you don't want to classify every image within the collection, but to generate a composite for the year, perhaps a median composite? This is how you could go about doing that:

```
var savi = function(image) {
  return image.expression('1.5 * (NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED + 5000)', {
    'NIR': image.select('B5'),
    'RED': image.select('B4')
  }).rename('SAVI')
}

//EVI: Enhanced Vegetation Index
var evi = function(image) {
  return image.expression('(2.5 * ((NIR - RED)) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
    'NIR': image.select('B5'),
    'RED': image.select('B4'),
    'BLUE': image.select('B2')
  }).rename('EVI')
}

var image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate('2014-01-01', '2015-01-01')
  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 10)
  .map(function (image) {
    return image // Add indexes to each image in the collection
      .addBands(savi(image))
      .addBands(evi(image))
  })
  .median()
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ad88f09e6d067133213dd325471c3bd4

Note that if you want to include the last day of the year in your collection, your date filter should be until `2015-01-01`. The end is exclusive - I see a lot of people getting that wrong.